# Laravel 7 change language of authentification forms

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-authentication

I would like to change langage of auth views in french.

I went to this github repo and downloaded it : [enter link description here](https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang)

I copied the necessaries files into ressources/lang/fr :

[image]

and I changed the app.php like this :

```
'locale' => 'fr',
```

but my forms still in english...

[image]

Comment: did you copy json files too?

Comment: thank you for your reply.  No, indeed.  Where can I copy the file please ?  Thanks again.

Comment: try to print out your `config('app.locale')` if it doesn't print out as **fr**, try `php artisan config:cache` then re-run your application

Comment: Thank you Saangdaet, I'm a noob sorry.  Where can I print out this command config('app.locale) ?  Like Hadi said, I didn't copy the json file, but I don't know where I can copy it.  Thank you to all of you.

Comment: @beegees just copy the fr.json to lang folder. lang/fr.json

Comment: Thank you great Hadi, I put fr.json into lang and it's working.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Like Hadi said, I just copied the fr.json into lang and it's working great.

[image]